# Achieving java enum like behaviour in ruby

Tags: ruby, enums

Can I create something in my model to do something like:

```
MyModel::TYPE::ONE
MyModel::TYPE::TWO
```

where `ONE` and `TWO` are strings? I placed them in a constant in my model like:

```
class MyModel
  TYPE = ['ONE', 'TWO']
end
```

so I can access `MyModel::Type` and get the array, but how do I get one more level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the syntax you desire with:

```
[~]$ irb
irb(main):001:0> module MyModel
irb(main):002:1>   module TYPE
irb(main):003:2>     ONE = 1
irb(main):004:2>     TWO = 2
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> 2
irb(main):007:0> MyModel::TYPE::ONE
=> 1
irb(main):008:0> MyModel::TYPE::TWO
=> 2
```

This has the disadvantage, or maybe the *advantage*, of allowing extra "attributes" on the enum, not unlike what Java gives you.  You can make the values of ONE and TWO be maps if you like, which is similar to Java's `enum` objects.

EDIT: You can also get the values like this:

```
irb(main):009:0> MyModel::TYPE::constants
=> [:ONE, :TWO]
```